# Ajax Async File Upload: On Upload Complete isn't triggering

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, asyncfileupload

Here is my html:

```
<ajax:asyncfileupload runat="server"  onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUploaderUploadedComplete" />
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void AsyncFileUploaderUploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
       string file = "Upload complete!";
    }
```

When I put a debug break on the string line and run the program, it never hits the debug line.  Any idea why the onUploadedComplete is not working?  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the html:

```
<ajax:asyncfileupload ID="fileupload1" runat="server"  onuploadedcomplete="AsyncFileUploaderUploadedComplete" />
```

Comment: Can you be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function startUpload() {
                document.forms[0].enctype = 'multipart/form-data';
            } </script>

         <ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" ID="asyncUploadMap" 
    OnUploadedComplete="asyncUploadMap_UploadedComplete" 
     OnClientUploadStarted="startUpload" OnClientUploadComplete="finishUpload" 
 UploaderStyle="Modern" />
```